# How do I get the day period from a week number

Tags: spotfire

I'm new to Spotfire. I have a problem where I want to get the following calculated value in a text area:

> Week #16: April 14-21, 2019

I need this week to change automatically when week #17 arrives.

I figured out how to get the week number but I didn't know how to get the corresponding day period.

I used the following expression to get "16" which is the week number

```
week(DateTimeNow())
```

I can't figure out how to get the following part: April 14-21, 2019

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: take a look here, https://community.tibco.com/questions/spotfire-format-date-or-datetime-string

Answer (score 1):

It's not terribly straight forward, but provided you can accept abbreviated month formatting (like 'Apr' instead of 'April') then this will work. I added some additional logic to deal with weeks which cross 2 months (like 'Week #18: Apr 28-May 5')

```
case  when Month(DateAdd("day",-dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow()))=Month(DateAdd("day",7 - dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow())) then 
        Concatenate("Week #",Week(datetimenow()),": ",Month(datetimenow())," ",DayOfMonth(DateAdd("day",-dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow())),"-",DayOfMonth(DateAdd("day",7 - dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow())))
else 
    Concatenate("Week #",Week(datetimenow()),": ",Month(DateAdd("day",-dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow()))," ",DayOfMonth(DateAdd("day",-dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow())),"-",Month(DateAdd("day",7 - dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow()))," ",DayOfMonth(DateAdd("day",7 - dayofweek(datetimenow()),datetimenow()))) 
end
```

Comment: oof, date math. you're a better person than me haha :) nice solution!